# Image exceeding height in div table cell

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit an image into a div (display: table cell).  The width never exceeds the width of the div but the height always does.  Although I think in IE 11 it's working fine because the overall size of the table is exactly correct.  But in Chrome the computed height is 9.297px; in Firefox the computed height is 10.5px.  The specified width and cell of the div
in CSS is 9 pixels by 9 pixels.  As you can see from the code below it is a table construction but in divs.  I've played around with it for ages with
the help of loads of posts on SO but I can't quite it to work perfectly.  To be clear, height, cannot exceed 9 pixels.

I just wondered if anybody had any ideas to get it to work.  As I say i think it's working in IE, just not the others.

I've included this JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/eermepfe/ .  It isn't an exact replica of my table.  I have so many cells it would look ridiculous in a jsfiddle.  Moreover the height stretch in the fiddle is even worse than my own broswer results; still it catches the problem.

Thanks for your help

```
<div id = "table">

<div class = "row">

<div class = "inner">

<img src = "image.png">

</div>

</div>


</div>
```

There are many rows and many divs in the rows but they follow the above set up.

```
CSS

#table{
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
height: 700px;
width: 1200px;
}

.row{
display:table-row;
}

.inner{
text-align: center;
line-height: 9px;
display: table-cell;
background-color: red;
height: 9px !important;
width: 9px;
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;  
}

img{
height: auto;
max-width: 9px;
vertical-align: middle;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `#table img { max-height: 9px; }` as well?

Comment: Yeah lol.  It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to `.inner` element

```
.inner{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:flex;
    align-items:flex-start;
}
```

Edited, Try these styles:

```
.table{
   width:100%;
}
.row{
   display:flex;
}
.inner{
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: This is good in Firefox and Chrome - but in addition to my css rules - don't know if you meant that.  It now makes IE11 go weird in terms of cell width.  Do you think there's a cross broswer solution or will i have to just use javascript and take each broswer into account thay way?

Comment: have you try this? `* { box-sizing: border-box } ` only. It must works cross browser. And I see the .inner element don't reach height 9px. Ignore the style i had given before. Only ad the * style

Comment: Yes but now I'm getting this effect in IE with the width - https://jsfiddle.net/0rfzs9kh/

Comment: may you just set the .inner element max-width: 9px ?